# Text Colour & Hover States

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am looking for some help, I am trying to modify the colour of the hover state of button on this page to match the input hover states as well as getting the new text that I have added to show in the right colour.

https://quotes.lasik-eyes.co.uk/free-laser-eye-quotes-v2

I have written this code so far:

```
$('#webform-container').css('float','right');
$("<div id=list></div>").insertBefore( "#webform-container").css('float','left').width(500);
$( "<ol id='uList'></ol>" ).appendTo( "#list" );
var benefitList = ["Save hundreds of pounds", "It takes less than 2 minutes"];
for(i = 0; i < benefitList.length; i++) {
    $("#uList").prepend("<li>" + benefitList[i] + "</li>")
}
$("#uList").css("text-align", "justify").css("text", "bold").css("color", "white").css("text-align", "justify").css("font-size", "35px").css('list-style-type', 'none');
$(".progressbar-text").text("Step 1 of 5");
$('em:contains("It only")').remove();
var newHTML = "@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) { .webformimage { background-image: url('http://www.scrubsandlabcoats.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/More-Expensive-Lab-Coats-624x284.jpg') !important } }"
$("body style:first-child").html(newHTML)
```

But I have spent over 3 hours trying to get the text colour to show in actual white and I am having no luck modifying the hover state colour of the button.

Comment: Why not use css to style the buttons and hover effect?

Comment: Because I am doing it for a presentation, and dont have the ability to modify the source code.

Comment: And where are you inserting your code now?

Comment: Also, I can't find your `#uList` on the page

Comment: I am injecting the code in to the console, it is for a presentation, hence I can't just update the source which would make it easy to fix.

Comment: In any modern browser you can as easily update the css in the developer tool.